# How to properly scale an 1x1px image?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

I'm having the following markup which is an 1x1px transparent gif:

```
<img class="dummy" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" width="600" height="2867">
```

This is a placeholder image until the real image is loaded. I know the exact width and height of the image, but the main issue is that the site is responsive. The image has `max-width: 100%;` of course. In a 300px width column the height is becoming also 300px, it won't scale by keeping the aspect-ratio.

Is there a way to achive this?

UPDATE:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kp3y2/1/

Comment: My guess is you can't without javascript. The browser scales the image according to the proportions of the original image. But you could have a transparent gif that is 1x5 px, should work...

Comment: Yeah, but the width/height ratio is not always 1:5, it can be horizontal image too like 3:2. Also i was thinking in the onload event of the image than calculate with JS by the parent width, but that's an ugly solution, searching for a cleaner one.

Comment: But if you know the w/h before the image loads then you could make the placeholder the same proportions as the original image? I mean different to adapt to each image?

Comment: But the continers are fluid...

Comment: Yeah that is what I mean. But the placeholder image itself must have the same proportions as the real image, not 1x1. See this example http://jsfiddle.net/bVSTD/

Comment: Exactly and that's an issue. There are no known proportions and i can't generate a dummy gif for all of them... But seems like you're the only who understands my problem :)

Comment: But if you can set the width/height attributes of the img tag then you must know the proportions also beforehand. Either way I would probably look at a javascript solution that resizes the placeholder from the parent container width relative the image w/h attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a javascript (jQuery) solution that works to scale an 1x1 image to desired proportions:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kp3y2/16/

I wrote this little function for you:

```
function resizeDummies()
{
    $('img.dummy').each(function()
    {
        var i = $(this);
        var iw = i.attr('width');
        var ih = i.attr('height');
        var pw = i.parent().width();
        var h = Math.round(pw*ih/iw); // calculates "fluid" height
        i.width(pw); // sets width = 100% of parent
        i.height(h); // sets height = as image proportions but scaled
    });
}
$(function() 
{ 
    resizeDummies(); 
});
$(window).resize(function() 
{ 
    resizeDummies(); 
});
```

It fixes image sizes for all dummy images both on load and on window resize. Of course it requires all w/h attributes to be set on the images.

Comment: I decided to use another display method as this can be achieved only with JavaScript. I accepted your answer anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is CSS

**CSS**

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

Comment: *The image has max-width: 100%;*

Comment: It's already auto, but seems like you don't get it, i'm putting together a JSFiddle...

Comment: No. I've added a fiddle also to the post.

Comment: Try it with setting the .item width to 5%

Answer (score 0):

did you try with css?

```
img{
   width:100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: of course, i just wanted to give an idea. i think Goombah send more spesific code.